# JSON Parsing in Android (Flickr API)

Tags: java, android, json

I've been looking extract image urls from the Flickr api for my android application.

More specifically, I need to parse the first `owner` and first `id` field for the following JSON

http://pastebin.com/NVKXdELx

Hence, I tried

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONObject photos = json.getJSONObject("photos");
JSONObject photo = photos.getJSONObject("photo");
String picOwner = photo.getString("owner");
String picID = photo.getString("id");
```

To me, the logic makes sense (grab the row photos, then grab the row photo, then extract the owner field as a string). However, an error is thrown on

```
JSONObject photo = photos.getJSONObject("photo");
```

Am I overlooking something?

Note: The ultimate values I am looking for are

```
    "id": "8637130199",
    "owner": "93693022@N07"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element identified by `"photo"` is a JSON Array, you need to use the `JSONArray` class

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONObject photos = json.getJSONObject("photos");
JSONArray photo = photos.getJSONArray("photo");
if (photo.length() > 0) {
    JSONObject first = photo.getJSONObject(0);
    String picOwner = first.getString("owner");
    String picID = first.getString("id");
}
```